# Can I use one row tag to form a multiple row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Would this be a valid thing to do? I have done it before and gives expected results, though I don't know if it's valid or if there is a negative to doing this.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
   <div class="col-md-12">.col-md-12</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap handles column gutters with margins, and then a negative margin on the `.row`. Generally you can place as many columns in a row as you wish, but it's better practice to work to the 12 columns per row rule.

Technically there's nothing 'invalid' about the way you're doing it, but it's much cleaner (IMHO) to separate them into rows:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">.col-md-12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I'd agree. Just more stuff to code when handling user data. Which is why i wanted to know if it was okay to do. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 1):

Seems acceptable, albeit not encouraged, as even the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) notes it:

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of
>   extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.